# How can I get notified of an answer?

Tags: support, notifications, email

I would like an email notification when someone responds to or comments on my question. Is that possible and, if so, how do I set that up? If it's stated somewhere, I didn't know where to look.

Comment: Whats wrong with just logging in and checking your notifications?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thats actually a MSO question. Its a duplicate

Comment: @BradleyDotNET ... confused myself, was also looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171051/248731